# Error generating API with openapi 3.0.1 in WSO2 EI

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, openapi-generator, ei

I am working with WSO2 EI 6.6 and I am testing the "Generate API" feature from a Swagger definition. I found out that the generation success using the swagger 2.0 spec but if I convert to OpenAPI 3, the generation fails.

The error shown is the following:

```
TID: [-1234] [] [2020-01-15 14:12:18,653] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.rest.api.service.RestApiAdmin} - Error occurred while generating API :: The "basePath" of the swagger definition is mandatory for API generation org.wso2.carbon.mediation.commons.rest.api.swagger.APIGenException: The "basePath" of the swagger definition is mandatory for API generation
at org.wso2.carbon.mediation.commons.rest.api.swagger.APIGenerator.generateSynapseAPI(APIGenerator.java:76)
```

It looks like the WSO2 EI 6.6 autogeneration tool only supports swagger 2.0 since it is missing a field that I think it is not present in OpenAPI 3

Any help? Is not there support for OpenAPI 3?

Cheers

Comment: just FYI: WSO2 APIM 3.0 supports OAS3

Comment: I know, but my problem is in EI